# How do you stop file renaming in file server?

Tags: file-management, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I have installed windows server 2008 r2 and configured FSRM role properly. I have enabled file screening there and blocked all types `(*.*)` of files to be saved there and have created an exclude lists for authenticated types of file.

Everything is working fine, but during an audit found that users are changing the file extensions of blocked files to the allowed files and then dumping it in file server over the network.

Even though file screening is enabled and working properly, users are able to save unauthenticated files in file server. How can I prevent this from happening?